# Why does strtok_s return 0x00000001 after first use?

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, strtok

I am facing some issues while using `strtok_s`. In the below code, `read_data` contains the string:

```
BEGIN_TRANSACTION CHANGE_0 PUT(debit_account,dbvalue.new)PUT(debit_account,dbvalue.new) CHANGE_0 PUT(credit_account,crvalue.new)PUT(credit_account,crvalue.new) OUTCOME_COMMITTED_0 END_TRANSACTION_0
```

Below is my code:

```
char *delim = " ";
char* next_token;
line[0] = strtok_s(read_data, delim, &next_token);
while (line[i] = strtok_s(NULL, delim, &next_token) != NULL)
{
    i++;
}
```

After execution, only `line[0]` contains correct string "BEGIN_TRANSACTION". All the other `line[i]`'s contains "0x00000001 ". I have looked up online but I am unable to find a solution here. 
Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (line[i] = strtok_s(NULL, delim, &next_token) != NULL)
```

The above line should be as shown below. Note the brackets.

```
while ((line[i] = strtok_s(NULL, delim, &next_token)) != NULL)
```

To explain: The original `while` condition is not correct due to the operator order of precedence. It equates to:

```
line[i] = (strtok_s(NULL, delim, &next_token) != NULL)
```

Which means it takes the result of comparing the `strtok_s` return value to `NULL` and assigns that to `line[i]`. Which is why you get `1` for `line[i]` (except the last entry should be 0).